# ACTION_DOWN not called for multiple touch events of various views in android recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-imageview, android-view, android-touch-event

I have a recyclerview, which has multiple imageviews. The view pressed & released events are to be captured, which should work even for multiple imageviews being touched at same time and being listened in a common function.

I have managed to listen to **ACTION_DOWN (0), ACTION_MOVE(2) & ACTION_UP (1)** events for one view at a time clicks.

But, when I click, more than one imageviews simultenously, it does not detect ACTION_DOWN for subsequent views & instead begins with ACTION_MOVE. ACTION_UP is fired at end.

Here is a log with timestamp, events and view names

```
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461653522 0-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461653543 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461653559 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461653575 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461653592 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461653609 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461653629 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461653643 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461653659 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461653676 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 -----trimmed because of too much repeatation------
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655222 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655238 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655254 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655271 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655289 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655305 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655323 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655339 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655356 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655372 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655378 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655379 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655406 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655406 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655423 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655424 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655439 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655440 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655456 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655457 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655473 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655473 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655492 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655492 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655506 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655506 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655522 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655523 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655539 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655540 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655557 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655557 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655573 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655573 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655590 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655591 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655607 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655608 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655623 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655623 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655641 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655642 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655658 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655658 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655673 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655674 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655691 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655691 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655708 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655709 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655725 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655725 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655741 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655742 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655758 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655759 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655775 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655775 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655792 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655792 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655809 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655809 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655825 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655825 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655843 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655843 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655859 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655859 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655875 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655876 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655892 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655893 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655909 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655910 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655926 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655926 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655943 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655943 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655959 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655960 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655976 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655977 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655993 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461655993 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656010 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656010 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656026 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656027 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656043 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656043 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656060 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656060 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656076 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656077 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656094 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656095 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656110 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656111 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656127 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656127 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656144 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656144 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656161 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656161 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656177 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656178 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656194 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656195 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656211 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656211 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656228 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656228 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656245 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656245 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656261 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656262 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656278 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656279 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656295 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656295 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656311 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656312 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656329 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656329 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656345 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656346 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656362 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656363 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656381 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656381 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656395 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656396 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656412 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656413 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656429 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656430 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656446 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656447 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656463 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656464 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656480 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656480 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656498 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656499 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656513 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656513 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656530 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656530 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656547 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656547 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656564 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656564 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656580 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656581 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656597 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656598 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656614 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656615 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656630 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656631 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656648 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656648 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656664 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656665 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656682 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656682 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656698 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656698 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656714 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656715 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656731 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656732 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656748 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656749 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656765 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656766 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656782 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656783 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656799 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656800 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656815 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656816 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656832 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656832 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656849 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656849 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656866 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656867 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656883 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656884 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656900 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656901 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656917 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656917 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656933 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656934 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656952 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656953 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656969 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656970 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656985 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461656986 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657002 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657003 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657024 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657026 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657027 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657028 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657029 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657035 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657035 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657036 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657051 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657052 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657052 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657068 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657069 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657070 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657085 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657086 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657086 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657102 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657103 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657104 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657118 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657119 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657119 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657138 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657139 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657141 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657152 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657152 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657153 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657168 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657168 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657168 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657184 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657185 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657185 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657202 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657202 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657202 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657218 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657218 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657218 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657235 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657235 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657235 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657252 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657252 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657252 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657269 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657269 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657270 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657285 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657285 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657286 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657302 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657302 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657303 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657320 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657320 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657320 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657337 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657337 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657338 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657354 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657354 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657355 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657369 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657370 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657370 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657386 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657387 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657387 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657403 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657403 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657403 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657420 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657421 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657421 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657436 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657437 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657437 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657453 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657454 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657454 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657470 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657471 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657471 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657487 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657487 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657488 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657503 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657504 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657504 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657521 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657521 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657522 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657537 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657538 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657538 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657554 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657554 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657739 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657756 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657757 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657757 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657772 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657773 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657773 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657790 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657790 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657791 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657806 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657806 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657807 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657823 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657823 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657823 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657839 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657840 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657840 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657857 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657858 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657858 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657873 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657873 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657874 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657891 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657891 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657892 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657906 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657907 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657907 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657923 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657924 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657924 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657940 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657940 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657941 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657956 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657957 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657957 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657973 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657974 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657974 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657990 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657991 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461657991 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658007 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658007 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658008 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658024 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658024 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658024 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658041 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658042 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658042 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658057 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658058 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658058 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658074 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658075 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658075 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658092 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658092 2-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658093 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658103 1-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658103 1-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658103 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658104 1-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658104 1-EVENT View::imgview_2
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658107 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658111 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658111 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658124 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658124 2-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658130 1-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658130 1-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658130 1-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658130 1-EVENT View::imgview1
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658143 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658157 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658174 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658192 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658208 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658225 2-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658235 1-EVENT View::imgview_three
 touchListener: timestamp 1587461658235 1-EVENT View::imgview_three
```

Additional info: I have blocked RecyclerView scroll in `onInterceptTouchEvent` with `rv.scrollState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING`, but I dont suspect any issues there as single touch works fine.

There is no use of gesture or scale listener in code

The selectors applied on imageviews are not having any problem setting *android:state_pressed, android:state_focused, android:state_selected* corresponding images in *multi touch/click/select* scenario.
So the XML view part driven by native code is solid, but touchListener side can't benefit from this working accuracy. **Or can it**?

Is this how touch listener functions listening to multiple view touches are supposed to work?

If **yes** - I will have to write a dumb fix of treating first ACTION_MOVE as ACTION_DOWN which is performance rabbit hole with keeping track of views in memory over such rapid function calls.

**Edit:** The function being modified

```
    imgview1.onTouch {v, event -> touchListener(v, event, position)}
    imgview_2.onTouch {v, event -> touchListener(v, event, position)}
    imgview_three.onTouch {v, event -> touchListener(v, event, position)}

    private fun touchListener(v: View, event: MotionEvent, position: Int): Boolean {
        var globalRect = Rect()
        v.getGlobalVisibleRect(globalRect)
        println("actionMasked ^^^ pointers-${event.pointerCount} time-${System.currentTimeMillis()} ${event.actionMasked}-EVENT View::${v.id}")

        return true     // tried with return false as well, true gave me pointer count of 3 once when i touched 4 buttons
    }
```

Comment: [Android_Touch_and_Multi-touch_Event_Handling_in_Android_Studio](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Touch_and_Multi-touch_Event_Handling_in_Android_Studio)
this article mentions `event.getPointerCount()` can help identify all touch points, but [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent) doesn't show, which action is being done at which pointer for multi touch

Comment: Related read https://stackoverflow.com/a/22434199/1029110 @gabe-sechan

Comment: If one finger is already touching, you don't get an ACTION_DOWN event.  You get an ACTION_POINTER_DOWN for all touches after the first until all touches are ended.

Comment: Ohkay. Yes finger is already pressed.  I have printed MotionEvent.action for all onTouch function calls. For getting action_pointer_down what to be used?

Comment: I guess, it's motionevent.getActionMasked( ) Thank you.

Comment: The deprecated MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked is replaced with MotionEvent.getActionMasked https://stackoverflow.com/a/47543497/1029110 
But, the events caught are ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN (261), ACTION_POINTER_1_DOWN (5), etc which are Deprecated. Event.pointerCount never has more than 2 pointers active, even when there are 4 touches.  a) How to return non deprecated actions? b) How to detect more than 2 pointers @GabeSechan

Comment: I am ok with deprecated code writing, as long as it works. So, I am including cases for pointer_1, pointer_2 & pointer_3 UP & DOWN and sadly, there are no more than 3 of them. 

Current Issue c) ACTION_POINTER_1_DOWN is called with imgview1 and from next event onwards which is ACTION_MOVE, the imgview_2 is associated to it, which is not at all helpful